# Use string array to select columns with AR and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a full set of items - `["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]` and for a certain entity I need to select only e subset of those. I keep this information as array for each entity `items = ["A", "C", "D"]`.

Each item is a column in a table. What I want is by using the array to select only those columns which are in the array for the given entity.

For example if I have

```
object.items = ["A", "C", "D"]
```

I want to have this SQL query executed

`SELECT A, C, D FROM table WHERE...`

But I need this done with ActiveRecords. So something like:

```
Entity.select(columns: items)..
```

Of course this is just a pseudocode. I don't know how to actually do it with AR, but I think that there is a good chance to have something build in which allows to perform such a select?

Comment: @ray I can think fo some hacks which will make this work but I wonder if there is a "clean" way of doing this. The array holds the names of the columns that I'm interested in. Want I want is ActiveRecord to recognise the elements in the array as table column names. If this is possible of course.

Comment: @Leron Sorry I got your point late, but see answer, if needed addition, I will edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
Entity.select(items.map(&:to_sym))
```

But make sure items get all correct column names.

Answer (score 3):

You can do as below,

```
Entity.select(*items)
```

As below,

```
array = ['id', 'client_name']

Event.select(*array)
  Event Load (1.6ms)  SELECT `events`.`id`, `events`.`client_name` FROM `events`
```

Comment: What does  `*`  do , Can you please explain  ?

Comment: @ts When you want to pass array elements in method call as arguments and if you directly pass array to it, it will consider it as single argument of type array. If you want to decompose it with elements, do like this. :)

Comment: @ts In case of `select`, it will automatically decompose array so using `select(array)` is also fine but this is preferred way while passing argument to methods